# SSRS Alpha Numeric value Search

Tags: mdx, ssrs-2012, mdxclient

My SSRS report is connected to SSAS. I have a parameter called Plant Code. In data base my plant code is in alpha numeric format like '02plant123'. Wen i search the report with a plant code the following error occurs 'plant123' not fount and by default the numerics before the text are getting removed. what kind of conversions are to be made in my MDX so that the numerics are also considered?

Comment: Share a sample of your dimension attributes values and the values you are using for the pareter. Also the MDX script you have could be useful.

Comment: @Alejandro i have palnts dimesion they hae attributes like plantid,plantcode,location and my measure has experiments conducted and results which are numeric values. So my MDX query purpose was to have a ssrs report showing how many lab test were performed in a particular plant. so when a user types his plantcode which is a atttribute in the palntdimenision the report shows the number of tests and results of that test in a table in ssrs. So my plant code has aplha numeric values and the numerics before the characters are ignored in ssrs as i mention above

Comment: @alejandrozuleta           my MDX query looks like this                                                                                                   SELECT NON EMPTY 
 { [Measures].[Result] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { ( 
 
 [DimTest].[Test Name].[Test Name].ALLMEMBERS 

 *[DimPlant].[Plant Code].[Plant Code].ALLMEMBERS 
 ) }  ON ROWS
  FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@plantcode) ) ON COLUMNS 

FROM [LIMSInstCube]) )

Comment: sorry for late reply. This problem hasnt solved and is really eating my time out   :(

Comment: Is your parameter Text type? Note `STRTOSET` **does not** convert `02plant123` in `[DimPlant].[Plant Code].&[02plant123]`.

Comment: yes it is next type. but in parameter type we don't have any other type that matches my data type in SSRS. There will be hundreds of plant codes and it is not a logical step to put them as multi parameter drop down list because its not meaning full for the client to search through big list of all plant codes. The scenario is only when client types the plant code he will get to see all analysis made in that plant.

Comment: Can some one please help me by an alternative it is really eating up a lot of time